# How can I get a list of posts with the user who created them?

Tags: javascript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Post entity class contains a many to one relationship with my Users entity:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Users, user => user.posts)
user: Users;
```

Users entity class contains a one to many relationship with my Post entity:

```
@OneToMany(() => Post, post => post.user)
posts: Post[];
```

I have a query which returns the list of posts with the user:

```
@Query(() => [Post])
async getAllUserPosts(@Ctx() context: MyContext) {

try {
  const qb = getConnection()
    .getRepository(Post)
    .createQueryBuilder("p")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("p.user", "u", "u.id = p.userID")
    .where("p.userID = :id", { id: 7 })
    .orderBy("p.datePublished", "DESC")

    const posts = await qb.getMany();

    console.log(posts)

    return posts

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

When I run the query it returns the following:
[image: list of posts and the user]

How can I return this data in GraphQL? I have attempted the following:
[image: GraphQL query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well aren't I silly...

I forgot to add the type of field for each relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(() => Users, user => user.posts)
@Field(() => Users)
user: Users;

@OneToMany(() => Post, post => post.user)
@Field(() => [Post])
posts: Post[];
```